# encoding list of files in directory

Tags: php, html

Hi i have php which shows me all files in dir and make them href. But i have troubles with encoding. when i open file in web usin this php page, encoding is wrong. adding meta charset in head is not helping.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
     if ($handle = opendir('/opt/nagios/share/kpi_backup')) {
       while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
          {
              if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
              {
                    $thelist .= '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
              }
           }
      closedir($handle);
      }

    ?>
    <p>List of files:</p>
    <p><?=$thelist?></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use `htmlentities()` to encode everything properly.

Comment: can You give an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/htmlentities) to encode everything properly:

```
$thelist .= '<a href="'.htmlentities($file) .'">'.htmlentities($file).'</a>';
```

Comment: thanks but its not working for me, tried htmlentities($file,"windows-1251")